# Problems PHP MARIADB PHPMYADMIN using docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

I've been this last two weeks searching how to link my phpmyadmin and my database, to create a PHP development workspace, through docker-compose but I am not able to connect to the database through the phpmyadmin port.

```
    version: '3'
services: 
 servicio_php:
  image: php:7.3-rc-apache
  volumes:
   - ./web/:/var/www/html
  expose:
   - "80"
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  links:
   - db

 db:
  image: mariadb:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./Volumenes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root123
    MYSQL_USER: user
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: user123
    MYSQL_DATABASE: bbdd1
  expose:
    - "3306"
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"

 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
  container_name: phpmyadmin
  environment:
   PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root123
   MYSQL_USERNAME: user
   PMA_HOST: db
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: user123
  restart: always
  ports: 
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - ./sessions:/sessions/
  depends_on: 
   - db 
  links: 
   - db
```

I am using windows 10 version of dockers 18.06.1-ce and also when i run docker-compose up i see there are some probles with Innodb but ive read is not a problem.

I am  not able to see whats wrong and probably I am not the only one with this problem.

Comment: Please read the phpmyadmin’s image documentation how to use it and which env variables to set.

Comment: i've cheked it and im still unable to find the problem.

Comment: Did you try it with an older version of mariadb? I remember something I had some similar issue a while ago with MySQL and phpmyadmin and it was because of an issue with the newer version. Maybe try with a 10 and a 5 version

Comment: I will try it, lets see if it works

Comment: I ran docker-compose on a CentOS 7 with docker 18.06.1-ce using exactly the file you provided and it worked perfectly. My local IP is 192.168.x.y, so I was able to access phpmyadmin interface at http://192.168.x.y:8080/ and from there to login to mariadb using 192.168.x.y as host and using either user/user123 or root/root123 as credentials. No problems at all. You can also use 'db' for the hostname in phpmyadmin, as 'db' is the service name of the database server.What exactly is the issue you faced? Can you paste some errors here?

Comment: Ive change it to mysql and it works, i think mariadb gives problems with widows thats why im not able of making it work. Thank you all for your answers